# Red Dot Tracker

Tags: python, opencv, analysis

I am coding a program that can monitor the red dot of a lazer and track the movement. I would like to collect the x and y movement of the laser (deviating from a stable point). Some searching found me this code on git hub which I plan to modify and use to track the red dot using openCV. I am however struggling to pull any data from this.

How would I go about storing the x and y coordinates of the laser in excel (or other useful means)?

```
import sys
import argparse
import cv2
import numpy

class LaserTracker(object):

        def __init__(self, cam_width=640, cam_height=480, hue_min=20, hue_max=160,
                 sat_min=100, sat_max=255, val_min=200, val_max=256,
                 display_thresholds=False):
        """
        * ``cam_width`` x ``cam_height`` -- This should be the size of the
        image coming from the camera. Default is 640x480.
        HSV color space Threshold values for a RED laser pointer are determined
        by:
        * ``hue_min``, ``hue_max`` -- Min/Max allowed Hue values
        * ``sat_min``, ``sat_max`` -- Min/Max allowed Saturation values
        * ``val_min``, ``val_max`` -- Min/Max allowed pixel values
        If the dot from the laser pointer doesn't fall within these values, it
        will be ignored.
        * ``display_thresholds`` -- if True, additional windows will display
          values for threshold image channels.
        """

        self.cam_width = cam_width
        self.cam_height = cam_height
        self.hue_min = hue_min
        self.hue_max = hue_max
        self.sat_min = sat_min
        self.sat_max = sat_max
        self.val_min = val_min
        self.val_max = val_max
        self.display_thresholds = display_thresholds

        self.capture = None  # camera capture device
        self.channels = {
            'hue': None,
            'saturation': None,
            'value': None,
            'laser': None,
        }

        self.previous_position = None
        self.trail = numpy.zeros((self.cam_height, self.cam_width, 3),
                                 numpy.uint8)

    def create_and_position_window(self, name, xpos, ypos):
        """Creates a named widow placing it on the screen at (xpos, ypos)."""
        # Create a window
        cv2.namedWindow(name)
        # Resize it to the size of the camera image
        cv2.resizeWindow(name, self.cam_width, self.cam_height)
        # Move to (xpos,ypos) on the screen
        cv2.moveWindow(name, xpos, ypos)

    def setup_camera_capture(self, device_num=0):
        """Perform camera setup for the device number (default device = 0).
        Returns a reference to the camera Capture object.
        """
        try:
            device = int(device_num)
            sys.stdout.write("Using Camera Device: {0}\n".format(device))
        except (IndexError, ValueError):
            # assume we want the 1st device
            device = 0
            sys.stderr.write("Invalid Device. Using default device 0\n")

        # Try to start capturing frames
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(device)
        if not self.capture.isOpened():
            sys.stderr.write("Faled to Open Capture device. Quitting.\n")
            sys.exit(1)

        # set the wanted image size from the camera
        self.capture.set(
            cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH if cv2.__version__.startswith('2') else cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,
            self.cam_width
        )
        self.capture.set(
            cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT if cv2.__version__.startswith('2') else cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,
            self.cam_height
        )
        return self.capture

    def handle_quit(self, delay=10):
        """Quit the program if the user presses "Esc" or "q"."""
        key = cv2.waitKey(delay)
        c = chr(key & 255)
        if c in ['c', 'C']:
            self.trail = numpy.zeros((self.cam_height, self.cam_width, 3),
                                     numpy.uint8)
        if c in ['q', 'Q', chr(27)]:
            sys.exit(0)

    def threshold_image(self, channel):
        if channel == "hue":
            minimum = self.hue_min
            maximum = self.hue_max
        elif channel == "saturation":
            minimum = self.sat_min
            maximum = self.sat_max
        elif channel == "value":
            minimum = self.val_min
            maximum = self.val_max

        (t, tmp) = cv2.threshold(
            self.channels[channel],  # src
            maximum,  # threshold value
            0,  # we dont care because of the selected type
            cv2.THRESH_TOZERO_INV  # t type
        )

        (t, self.channels[channel]) = cv2.threshold(
            tmp,  # src
            minimum,  # threshold value
            255,  # maxvalue
            cv2.THRESH_BINARY  # type
        )

        if channel == 'hue':
            # only works for filtering red color because the range for the hue
            # is split
            self.channels['hue'] = cv2.bitwise_not(self.channels['hue'])

    def track(self, frame, mask):
        """
        Track the position of the laser pointer.
        Code taken from
        http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/09/14/ball-tracking-with-opencv/
        """
        center = None

        countours = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                                     cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]

        # only proceed if at least one contour was found
        if len(countours) > 0:
            # find the largest contour in the mask, then use
            # it to compute the minimum enclosing circle and
            # centroid
            c = max(countours, key=cv2.contourArea)
            ((x, y), radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
            moments = cv2.moments(c)
            if moments["m00"] > 0:
                center = int(moments["m10"] / moments["m00"]), \
                         int(moments["m01"] / moments["m00"])
            else:
                center = int(x), int(y)

            # only proceed if the radius meets a minimum size
            if radius > 10:
                # draw the circle and centroid on the frame,
                cv2.circle(frame, (int(x), int(y)), int(radius),
                           (0, 255, 255), 2)
                cv2.circle(frame, center, 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)
                # then update the ponter trail
                if self.previous_position:
                    cv2.line(self.trail, self.previous_position, center,
                             (255, 255, 255), 2)

        cv2.add(self.trail, frame, frame)
        self.previous_position = center

    def detect(self, frame):
        hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

        # split the video frame into color channels
        h, s, v = cv2.split(hsv_img)
        self.channels['hue'] = h
        self.channels['saturation'] = s
        self.channels['value'] = v

        # Threshold ranges of HSV components; storing the results in place
        self.threshold_image("hue")
        self.threshold_image("saturation")
        self.threshold_image("value")

        # Perform an AND on HSV components to identify the laser!
        self.channels['laser'] = cv2.bitwise_and(
            self.channels['hue'],
            self.channels['value']
        )
        self.channels['laser'] = cv2.bitwise_and(
            self.channels['saturation'],
            self.channels['laser']
        )

        # Merge the HSV components back together.
        hsv_image = cv2.merge([
            self.channels['hue'],
            self.channels['saturation'],
            self.channels['value'],
        ])

        self.track(frame, self.channels['laser'])

        return hsv_image

    def display(self, img, frame):
        """Display the combined image and (optionally) all other image channels
        NOTE: default color space in OpenCV is BGR.
        """
        cv2.imshow('RGB_VideoFrame', frame)
        cv2.imshow('LaserPointer', self.channels['laser'])
        if self.display_thresholds:
            cv2.imshow('Thresholded_HSV_Image', img)
            cv2.imshow('Hue', self.channels['hue'])
            cv2.imshow('Saturation', self.channels['saturation'])
            cv2.imshow('Value', self.channels['value'])

    def setup_windows(self):
        sys.stdout.write("Using OpenCV version: {0}\n".format(cv2.__version__))

        # create output windows
        self.create_and_position_window('LaserPointer', 0, 0)
        self.create_and_position_window('RGB_VideoFrame',
                                        10 + self.cam_width, 0)
        if self.display_thresholds:
            self.create_and_position_window('Thresholded_HSV_Image', 10, 10)
            self.create_and_position_window('Hue', 20, 20)
            self.create_and_position_window('Saturation', 30, 30)
            self.create_and_position_window('Value', 40, 40)

    def run(self):
        # Set up window positions
        self.setup_windows()
        # Set up the camera capture
        self.setup_camera_capture()

        while True:
            # 1. capture the current image
            success, frame = self.capture.read()
            if not success:  # no image captured... end the processing
                sys.stderr.write("Could not read camera frame. Quitting\n")
                sys.exit(1)

            hsv_image = self.detect(frame)
            self.display(hsv_image, frame)
            self.handle_quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Run the Laser Tracker')
    parser.add_argument('-W', '--width',
                        default=640,
                        type=int,
                        help='Camera Width')
    parser.add_argument('-H', '--height',
                        default=480,
                        type=int,
                        help='Camera Height')
    parser.add_argument('-u', '--huemin',
                        default=20,
                        type=int,
                        help='Hue Minimum Threshold')
    parser.add_argument('-U', '--huemax',
                        default=160,
                        type=int,
                        help='Hue Maximum Threshold')
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--satmin',
                        default=100,
                        type=int,
                        help='Saturation Minimum Threshold')
    parser.add_argument('-S', '--satmax',
                        default=255,
                        type=int,
                        help='Saturation Maximum Threshold')
    parser.add_argument('-v', '--valmin',
                        default=200,
                        type=int,
                        help='Value Minimum Threshold')
    parser.add_argument('-V', '--valmax',
                        default=255,
                        type=int,
                        help='Value Maximum Threshold')
    parser.add_argument('-d', '--display',
                        action='store_true',
                        help='Display Threshold Windows')
    params = parser.parse_args()

    tracker = LaserTracker(
        cam_width=params.width,
        cam_height=params.height,
        hue_min=params.huemin,
        hue_max=params.huemax,
        sat_min=params.satmin,
        sat_max=params.satmax,
        val_min=params.valmin,
        val_max=params.valmax,
        display_thresholds=params.display
    )
    tracker.run()
```

Comment: Hi there, just some advice on asking good questions. Try to include as little code as possible. Also try to show how you have approached the problem, what your thoughts are, code written so far etc. You will get much more useful help and feedback.

Comment: Hi, yes I understand, however the posting the code in section is not useful in this case in my eyes due to to the fact that I do not know where the specific information i need is being processed. This is due to the fact that i am not experienced in coding. I have however tried to extract data from the 'track' function. I will try edit it to make it more useful.

Comment: Only had a quick look through this but it is looking like self.previous_position is a tuple containing the x and y coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm by no means an expert on this, but taking a quick look at the code it seems that self.previous_position = (x,y).

Not sure why you would want to save to excel but to save to file just add f = open(filename, 'w') at the start of the run function and then f.write(self.previous_position) at the end of each loop.

Your file will contain all the recorded x and y coordinates recorded, if your set on saving this to excel check out python's out-the-box csv library.

Comment: Thank you. I actually managed to find the X,Y coordinates using the 'center = int(x), int(y)'. I am creating a program to monitor a red dot and thus save the x and y coordinates over 60 seconds. I then have a post processing program that converts the displacements and time into the frequency domain. I just found saving to excel gave me more usability of the data.